# finding the kernel of a matrix in F_2

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose I have a matrix M  \begin{bmatrix}
       1 & 0 & 0 & 1           \\[0.3em]
       0 & 1 & 1 & 1         
     \end{bmatrix}
With its field being $\mathbb{F}_2$. How do I calculate its kernel?

Comment: Find all $\mathbf x = [x_1 x_2 x_3 x_4]^T$ such that $M \mathbf x = \mathbb 0$, keeping in mind that each $x_i$ is either $0$ or $1$ and doing calculations over $\mathbb F_2$.

Comment: You can read the kernel directly from a row-reduced echelon form matrix, which you have. See http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1521354/265466 for examples. This is equivalent to solving the equations, but much simpler.

Answer (score 1):

Set $x=\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\\x_4\end{bmatrix}$ and look at the equations you get from $Mx=0$.