# Find null space basis matlab

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matlab

I want to find the basis of null space in matlab. I know that I can find it by simply running `ns = null(A,'R')` or `Z = null(A)` but I was wondering what would be the way to that by "hand". What I wanna way is; Is there a way to find the null space basis of a matrix by running many for loops and ifs? If yes could you please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can code up row-reduction by “hand”, then you should be able to use either of the methods described [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1612735/265466) to find a kernel basis.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to find the null space basis of a matrix by running many for loops and ifs

Yes.

Wikipedia [explains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition#Applications_of_the_SVD) how you can use the Singular Value Decomposition to determine a basis for the nullspace of a matrix. The question then becomes "How do you calculate the SVD?", which wikipedia [also answers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition#Calculating_the_SVD), though its answer does not seem particularly enlightening. Maybe [this](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/inderjit/public_papers/HLA_SVD.pdf) is of more use.

Comment: Well, thanks for sharing but I don't think I'll be able to write that in matlab code, I am not so good :p