# General method to find basis for null space of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition

Given a matrix $A\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ I would like to find a basis for the null space
$$
N(A) = \left\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n\,:\, Ax = 0\right\}
$$
**automatically**.

> I am looking for a general strategy that I can code into software. I would like, if possible to avoid matrix decompositions, and if possible to specifically avoid computing the SVD. Is there a matrix formula (involving inverses, if needs be) giving a set of basis vectors?

Comment: Let $A'$ be the row reduced form of $A$, then simply augment $(A')^T$ with the identity matrix and row reduce it again. Then you can read the basis of the image and nullspace almost directly. See here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1612616/how-to-find-null-space-basis-directly-by-matrix-calculation

Comment: @Euler Would row-reduction work for your purposes, or would you prefer, for instance, a formula giving the entries of this basis in terms of determinants?