# Finding the dimension of range and null space given a matrix and determining bases

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

I am attempting to solve the following problem.

I am given the matrix A=\begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
        1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
        1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
        1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
        \end{pmatrix}

Specifically I am asked to: (1) find the dimension of the range of this matrix, (2) give a range for this subspace, (3) find the dimension of the null space of this matrix, and (4) give a basis for this subspace.

I just keep staring at the problem but can't seem to put my finger on how to tackle it since I am not given a linear transformation.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Just regard $A$ as a linear transformation. Then, range will be a set $\{A\mathbf{x}:\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{R}^4\}$ and null space be $\{\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{R}^4:A\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{0}\}$.

Answer (score 2):

Note that the $\ker A$ has dimension $3$ and is spanned by vector $(1,0,0,-1) ,(0,1,0,-1) , (0,0,1,-1)$ while $ Im A$ is spanned by vector $(1,1,1,1)$ Indeed to find $\ker A$ you have to solve a linear system $$\begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
        1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
        1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
        1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
        \end{pmatrix}\cdot 
\begin{pmatrix}
        X_1 \\
        X_2 \\
        X_3 \\
        X_4\\
        \end{pmatrix}= vector zero$$
Therefore you find that $X_1+X_2+X_3+X_4=0$

Comment: So when you mention that we have to solve a linear system to find ker A, are you saying that is how you find those spanning vectors? (1,0,0-1), (0,1,0,-1), and (0,0,1,-1)? Also, since you only have one linear equation to work with, are you basically just playing around with numbers and seeing what works?

Comment: @KingTut No, you don’t “just play around with numbers,” although in this case it is pretty easy so come up with a solution by inspection. You can use any of several methods to solve this system of linear equations, such as row-reduction. Once you have the row-reduced echelon form of the matrix, you can basically read off a basis for its kernel.

Comment: @amd Could you please provide such an example?

Comment: @KingTut There are several examples [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1521354/265466).

Comment: @amd Thanks amd!