# Trouble computing eigenvectors of 3x3 matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have the following matrix:

$$\left[\begin{matrix}-4 & 20 & -33 \\ 0 & 1 & 12 \\ 0 & 0 & 5\end{matrix}\right]$$

Since it is a triangular matrix, we have the eigenvalues: $-4,1,5$

Then, when I try to get the eigenvector for the eigenvalue $-4$.

A-In:
$$\left[\begin{matrix}0 & -20 & 33 \\ 0 & -5 & -12 \\ 0 & 0 & -9\end{matrix}\right]$$

Then I do its RREF:
$$\left[\begin{matrix}0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0\end{matrix}\right]$$

After this step, I get lost. Wouldn't the resulting vector be $\left[\begin{matrix}1 \\ 1 \\ 0\end{matrix}\right]$?

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Use & instead of \ to get proper spacing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After the *rref* you get the system:
$$\left(\begin{array}{ccc|c}
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
    \end{array}\right)
\sim
\cases{0x+y+0z = 0 \\
0x+0y+z = 0  \\
0x+0y+0z = 0 
} \Leftrightarrow
\cases{y = 0 \\
z = 0  
}$$
Choose $x=t$; then $(t,0,0)$ is an eigenvector for all $t \ne 0$; e.g. pick $(1,0,0)$.

Comment: Why is x being parametrized? Sorry, this is the step where I get lost, do you know of any tutorials that show how to do this?

Comment: Because the last row (and the corresponding equation) disappears, you then have a linear system of two equations in three unknowns. This means you'll be able to choose one variable freely, this is usually done by introducing a parameter. Since you cannot choose $y$ and $z$ in this case (they are both 0), you choose $x$.

Comment: @JackGal Do you know how to use a rref to construct a general solution to a system of equations? That is all that is being done here. When you do that, you solve for the pivot variables in terms of the free variables and then let the free variables be arbitrary parameters.

Comment: yep... sorry... somehow I thought that y and z were equal to 1... which is definitely wrong.. I am going to compute for lambda = 1, lets see if I can get it right

Comment: I am going to edit the question, if that is ok, or should I create a new question??

Comment: I get for lambda = 1 {{1,-4,0},{0,0,1},{0,0,0}}. After I have that x=4y & z=0, and I get stuck here... is it {{x,y,z}} = {b{4,1,0}}?

Comment: Good! Since $z=0$ and $x=4y$ has to be satisfied, you can take $y=t$ and then eigenvectors are of the form $(4t,t,0)$ for every non-zero $t$; e.g. pick $(4,1,0)$.

Comment: If you aren't sure, if it is an eigenvector use $A v = \lambda v$ where $v$ is your $eigenvector$ and $\lambda$ your corresponding $eigenvalue$.

Answer (score 0):

See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1521354/265466) for how to read a basis for the kernel of a matrix from its rref. In this case, the first column is the only one without a pivot, so the referenced procedure tells you that eigenvectors corresponding to $-4$ will be of the form $(x,0,0)^T$.