# Solving for eigenvector when there is a column of zeros.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

So I have this matrix here: 
$$
        \begin{matrix}
        0 & 2 & 0 \\
        0 & -1 & 1 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 \\
        \end{matrix}
$$
and I need to find the eigenvectors. I have already found the three eigenvalues of $0$, $-1$, and $1$. So, for $\lambda = 0$, I get this matrix:
$$
        \begin{matrix}
        0 & 2 & 0 \\
        0 & -1 & 1 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 \\
        \end{matrix}
$$
 but it has a column of zeros. I know there should be a free variable in this case but which one is it. After getting the variables, what would the eigenvector(s) in this case be.
Edit: added another similar case, this is the matrix after adding the eigenvalues:
$$
        \begin{matrix}
        0 & 1 & 1 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 \\
        \end{matrix}
$$
In this case, what would the eigenvectors be.

Comment: The first equation (with the $0$ included on the right side) implies $x_2=0$. The third similarly implies $x_3=0$. $x_1$ is not constrained (because it doesn't appear in any of the equations), so that's your free variable. One routine way to construct eigenvectors for a given eigenspace is to find all the free variables, then set all but one free variable equal to zero and set one of them equal to $1$.

Comment: Ok thank you very much, but I also encountered another question with a similar layout. When applying the eigenvalue on this matrix , the new matrix is has two rows of zeroes, and one column of zeros. I added it above, if you can, please answer for it too.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1521354/265466 for how to read a kernel basis from a rref matrix. It doesn’t cover your case—no pivot in the first column—explicitly, but the third method described there makes this a no-brainer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A non-zero vector ${\bf x}$ is in the eigenspace of 
$$
{\bf A} := \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 2 & 0 \\
0 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
with eigenvalue $\lambda = 0$ if and only if ${\bf A}{\bf x} = \lambda{\bf x} = 0\cdot {\bf x} = {\bf 0}$. In your case, this amounts to
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 2 & 0 \\
0 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
x_1\\
x_2 \\
x_3
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
0\\0\\0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
which happens if and only if 
$$
\begin{pmatrix} 
2x_2 \\
-x_2\\
x_3
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
0\\0\\0
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Here you can solve for $x_2 = 0$ and $x_3 = 0$, but there is no dependence on $x_1$, so you find that
$$
{\bf A}{\bf x} = 0\cdot{\bf x} \iff
{\bf x} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
x_1\\x_2\\x_3
\end{pmatrix}= 
\begin{pmatrix}
x_1\\0\\0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
where we see that $x_1$ is now playing the role of the "free variable"

Comment: Just a question, I added a similar case now in my edit. In this case, I get a vector with x2+x3,0,0. What would the free variable be in this case,

Comment: There would be two free variables in the second case since the dimension of the eigenspace with eigenvalue $0$ is two. Note that $x_1$ can be anything, and you only have the relation $x_2 + x_3 = 0$, so you can solve for $x_2$ as a function of $x_3$, say, and arrive at the solution $(x_1, -x_3 ,x_3)^{T} = x_1 (1, 0, 0)^{T} + x_3 (0, -1, 1)^{T}$.

Comment: Ok thank you very much.