# How to find the eigenvectors of this matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Given

$$A = \begin{bmatrix}
-9 & 4 & 4\\
-8 & 3 & 4 \\
-16 & 8 & 7
\end{bmatrix}$$

I calculated eigenvalues $\lambda= -1,-1,3$. The algebraic multiplicity (AM) and geometric multiplicity (GM) of $\lambda=-1$ are $2$, which tells us that there will be two linearly independent eigenvectors.

I am not sure how to find the eigenvectors. Usually, I take one variable and equate it to $t$ and then solve it for the other two. I am not quite sure how to find eigenvectors when we have two free variables.

Steps:

$$(A-\lambda I)=0$$

$$\begin{bmatrix}
-8 & 4 & 4\\
-8 & 4 & 4 \\
-16 & 8 & 8
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
 x \\
 y  \\
 z \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
 0\\
 0 \\
 0  
\end{bmatrix}$$

$$\begin{bmatrix}
8 & -4 & -4\\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
 x \\
 y  \\
 z \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
 0\\
 0 \\
 0  
\end{bmatrix}$$

$$2x-y-z=0$$

I don't know how to proceed from here.

Comment: So, $2x-y-z=0$.  Let us define some parametric variables.  Out of convenience, lets use the parameters $s$ and $t$ and let us use $y=s$ and $z=t$.  We have then $\begin{cases}x=\frac{1}{2}s+\frac{1}{2}t\\y=1s+0t\\z=0s+1t\end{cases}$.  Can you continue now?

Comment: Note: there are infinitely many correct answers.  The answer I lead you to above is just one of many.  You could have instead chosen to set $x=s$ and $y=t$ for example which would lead you to a different pair of eigenvectors.  The point is that any correct answer will have the span of the two vectors all corresponding to the same eigenspace.

Comment: Yes I understood little bit. I ll get back and ask if I am stuck again. @JMoravitz Thanks again .

Comment: @JMoravitz I have a problem. I am stuck. Three eigenvectors came $(1,1,0),(1,0,-1),(1,1,2)$. I have to Diagonalize it. My question is will it change determinant value if I take second vector$ (-1,0,1)$ in my second column instead of $(1,0,-1)$.

Comment: Of course the two determinants won’t be equal. You’re multiplying one of the columns by $-1$. Why does that matter?

Comment: @amd That was silly I know but it will not alter diagonalizaton.

Comment: Suppose you diagonalize $A$ in two different ways:  $A=SDS^{-1}$ as well as $A=TET^{-1}$ where $D$ and $E$ are both diagonal matrices whose entries are the eigenvalues of $A$ and $S$ and $T$ are both matrices whose columns are the corresponding eigenvectors.  It is possible for $\det(S)\neq \det(T)$, sure.  However... $\det(SDS^{-1})=\det(A)=\det(TET^{-1})$ so in that sense it doesn't matter at all which diagonalization you use.

Comment: Note that $\det(A)=\det(SDS^{-1})=\det(S)\det(D)\det(S^{-1})=\det(S)\cdot det(D)\cdot\frac{1}{\det(S)}=\det(D)$ is equal to the product of the eigenvalues of $A$.  The eigenvectors and the value of $\det(S)$ don't come into that calculation at all.  There are in fact infinitely many correct ways in which you can diagonalize a matrix.  Suppose $A=SDS^{-1}$ was a diagonalization.  So too is $A=(2S)D(2S)^{-1}=(3S)D(3S)^{-1}=\dots$ etc... Each of $(S),(2S),(3S),\dots$ obviously have different determinants.

Comment: As for your eigenvectors that you found, you must have made a mistake.  None of $(1,1,0),(1,0,-1),(1,1,2)$ correspond to eigenvalue $-1$.

Comment: See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1521354/265466) for a way to read a basis for the null space from the rref matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so 
$x=\lbrace\frac{y}{2}+\frac{z}{2} $

let be
$y=1$, $z=0$, then

$v1=\begin{bmatrix}\frac {1}{2} \\ {1}\\ {0} \end{bmatrix}$

let be
$y=0$, $z=1$, then
$v2=\begin{bmatrix}\frac {1}{2} \\ {0}\\ {1} \end{bmatrix}$

later, you only substitute $\lambda (i)$ and $v1$,$v2$ in the equations
$\ (A-\lambda I)v1=0$

and $\ (A-\lambda I)v2=0$

Comment: Could you please answer my question in comments ? . Thanks for ans btw

Answer (score 0):

The null space of a matrix is the orthogonal complement of its row space. The latter is clearly spanned by $(8,-4,-4)^T$, so you’re looking for a linearly independent pair of vectors orthogonal to this one. These can be found by inspection: for *any* vector $(a,b,c)^T$, the vectors $(0,c,-b)^T$, $(-c,0,a)^T$ and $(b,-a,0)^T$ are all orthogonal to it, and if $(a,b,c)^T\ne0$, then at least two of those orthogonal vectors are also nonzero.