# Basis from 2 equations

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors, self-learning

$V$ is the subspace in $\mathbb{R}^3$ consisting of vectors $(x,y,z)$ satisfying 
$x+2y-3z=0$ and 
$y-2z=0$. How do I find the basis of this space? 
I tried using RREF but it doesn't make sense. Is it the row space I should be looking at? That makes $(1,2,-3)$ and $(0,1,-2)$ the basis. How do I think about this?

Comment: You might find [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1521264/265466) helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intersection of two planes is a line. All you have to do is find one non -zero vector in the line. One such vector is $(-1,2,1)$.  So $\{(-1,2,1)\}$ is a basis.