# Determine the null space of the following matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Determine the null space of the following matrix:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & -3&  -1 \\   
      -2& -4 &6 &3 
\end{bmatrix}$$

For this question, I reduced the row echelon form into $$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & -3&  -1 \\   
      0& 0 &0 &1 
\end{bmatrix},$$ but then I have no idea how to determine the null space, because there's no relationship between $x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4$.

Comment: you are encouraged to include your attempt.

Comment: For this question, I reduced the row echelon form into ( 1 2 -3 -1  0 0 0 1 ), but then I have no idea how to determine the null space, because there's no relationship between x1, x2, x3, x4

Comment: Include your attempt in the original post directly.

Comment: You require $$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & -3&  -1 \\   
      0& 0 &0 &1 
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
x_1\\x_2\\x_3\\x_4
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
0\\ 0\\0\\0
\end{bmatrix}$$ Now just find the relations between $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4$ as in the answer below.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1521354/265466 for how to read a basis for the null space directly from the RREF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great that you have found a row echelon form.

From the second row, we can conclude that $x_4=0$.

Also, from there, and the first row of the row echelon form, we have

$$x_1+2x_2-3x_3=0$$

Now you have a relationship between the variables. Hopefully you can take it from here.

Comment: Thanks!  Then I set x2=α, x3= β, then x1 = 3β-2α. So the null space is spanned by α(-2 1 0 0)^T + β(3 0 1 0)^T, is that true?

Comment: @ShadowZ Yes, that is correct

Comment: Congratulations, good job. try to pick up mathjax, it makes maths prettier and more importantly makes communication smoother.