# Determine the dimension and find a basis of a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> $V_1 = (x_1, ..., x_7)^T \in \mathbb{Z}^7_{5} : x_1 + 3x_2 +x_3+2x_4+3x_5+x_6+2x_7 = 0$
>
> $3x_1 + 4x_2 +3x_3+x_4+4x_5+2x_6+4x_7 = 0$
>
> $2x_1 + x_2 +4x_3+4x_5+x_6+2x_7 = 0$

I am supposed to find the dimension and some basis of this vector space.

After putting these equations in matrix form and doing gaussian elimination I got this matrix, but I don't know what to do now, any help would be appreciated
$$\left(\begin{matrix} 1 & 3 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 1 & 2\\ 0 & 0 & 2 & 1 & 3 & 3& 3\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 4  & 3\end{matrix}\right)$$

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1521354/265466 for how to read a kernel basis from the rref.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume that your Gaussian elimination is correct and explain how to proceed with the matrix you gave.

You have pivot positions corresponding to $x_{1},x_{3},$ and $x_{6}$. That means your matrix has rank $3$ so its null space, which is what we're after, has dimension $7-3=4$. Let's solve for the pivot variables in terms of the free ones. From the last equation, $4x_{6}=-3x_{7}$ can be rewritten $-x_{6}=-3x_{7}$ since we are in $\mathbb{Z}_{5}$. Now multiply both sides by $-1$ to get $x_{6}=3x_{7}$.

For the middle equation, we have
$$2x_{3}=-x_{4}-3x_{5}-3x_{6}-3x_{7}$$
Multiplying both sides by $3$, and simplifying/rewriting mod $5$ gives
$$x_{3}=2x_{4}+x_{5}+x_{6}+x_{7}$$
which, substituting in what we found previously, becomes
$$x_{3}=2x_{4}+x_{5}+3x_{7}+x_{7}=2x_{4}+x_{5}+4x_{7}$$

Finally, repeat for the first equation. Starting with
$$x_{1}=-3x_{2}-x_{3}-2x_{4}-3x_{5}-x_{6}-2x_{7}$$
substitute in for $x_{3}$ and $x_{6}$ to get
\begin{align}
x_{1} &= -3x_{2}-(2x_{4}+x_{5}+4x_{7})-2x_{4}-3x_{5}-3(x_{7})-2x_{7} \\
&= -3x_{2}-4x_{4}-4x_{5}-4x_{7}\\
&\equiv 2x_{2}+x_{4}+x_{5}+x_{7}
\end{align}

Now we can conclude. The solution set is all vectors of the following form
\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}
x_{1}\\
x_{2}\\
x_{3}\\
x_{4}\\
x_{5}\\
x_{6}\\
x_{7}\\
\end{pmatrix}
= 
\begin{pmatrix}
2x_{2}+x_{4}+x_{5}+x_{7}\\
x_{2}\\
2x_{4}+x_{5}+4x_{7}\\
x_{4}\\
x_{5}\\
3x_{7}\\
x_{7}\\
\end{pmatrix}=
x_{2}\begin{pmatrix}2\\1\\0\\0\\0\\0\\0\\\end{pmatrix}
+x_{4}\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\2\\1\\0\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}
+x_{5}\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\1\\0\\1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}
+x_{7}\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\1\\0\\0\\3\\1\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

Therefore a basis is given by 
$$\begin{pmatrix}2\\1\\0\\0\\0\\0\\0\\\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\2\\1\\0\\0\\0\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\1\\0\\1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\1\\0\\0\\3\\1\end{pmatrix}$$
and the dimension is $4$.