# Find the vector $v$ such that there are an infinite number of solutions to the system of equations of the form $x^{*} + kv$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Q: The system of equations:

$2x_{1}+x_{2}+3x_{3}=b_{1}$

$x_{2}+x_{3}=b_{2}$

$x_{1}+x_{3}=b_{3}$

b) Find the vector $v$ such that there are an infinite number of solutions to the system of equations of the form $x^{*} + kv$

Understanding:

I've attached a photo of the question with my attempts to the post.

I've reduced the matrix to echelon form to find solutions for $x_{1}, x_{2}, x_{3}$ and also using the assumption that  $b_{1}= 2b_{3}+b_{2}$, arrived to the confirmation that all 3 equations are independent, and the existance of more free variables than non zero rows leads to the conclusion of infinite solutions. However, I ended up going full circle achieving the equations that were given, and still unsure how to put in the required vector notation.

[Revised solution for part A, and full question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XdcxJ.jpg)

[Solution for part 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EPOLW.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you were able to reduce the matrix to the identity matrix, the solution you found was unique. Note that this reduction can be done regardless of the values of $b_1,b_2,b_3$ (as you did it), so you can always find a unique solution. Since the solution is always unique, the question asking to describe infinite solutions doesn't make sense.

Perhaps you should double-check your row reduction. You should get a solution with a free parameter (perhaps, say, x_3), and then you can rewrite the solution as $w+x_3v$ for some known vectors $w,v$, which answers the question.

Also, I think part (b) is following up on part (a), i.e., you are assuming $b_1=2b_3+b_2$. Otherwise there may not be a solution.

Comment: Hi there, thank you so much for your response! You were right, I did make a mistake in my reduction, but using the assumption you mentioned, I managed to get a sensible result at the end. However, I ended up going full circle and produced the equations they originally gave us! In the description is my updated attempt. Although I understand the mechanics of row reduction, I don't really understand the translation to vector form

Comment: @ReeceBuckle When there is dependency in your equations, you need to assign one (or more) variable to be a free parameter. It's easiest to use the columns without pivots as the free variables, so in this case $x_3$. Then you want to solve for the other variables in terms of $x_3$, and finally write the whole solution in vector form.

Comment: Thank you :) I have arrived at a solution I am satisfied with now.

Comment: @Reece See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1521354/265466) for a detailed description of how to read a basis for the null space of a matrix directly from its RREF.

Comment: @amd thank you that's very insightful!

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Multiplying the third equation by $(-2)$ and adding to the first we get
$$x_2+x_3=b_1-2b_3$$ and the second equation is given by
$$x_2+x_3=b_2$$
Can you proceed?

Comment: Thank you for your help! I updated my solution to part A as this is a much more solid solution