# What algorithm is used to list all linearly independent (LI) solution of a homogeneous system Ax = 0?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, algorithms, homogeneous-equation

The is an example:

```
x1 + x2 - x4 = 0
x1 + x3 - x5 = 0
```

The solutions are: (1,0,0,1,1), (0,1,1,0,0), (0,0,0,1,1). We know that there are 3 such solution, because there are 2 LI equations where there should be 5, and 5-2 = 3. We can find them by hand.

But how does a computer find these 3 solutions algorithmically? Or more generally:

**How does a computer find all linearly independent solution of Ax = 0 ?** Assuming there's always at least one solution.

Thank you.

Comment: Well, there’s always at least one solution to a homogeneous system of linear equations: 0.

Answer (score 1):

The one that is taught most often in linear algebra classes is the process of [Gaussian Elimation.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination)

It works by converting the system of equations into matrix form and then by performing a series of elementary row operations. It can be done by hand and a variant of it is useful for finding matrix inverses if they exist.

Comment: You don't *have to* convert the system into the matrix form. The Gaussian elimination can be done in the equation form also.

Comment: Once you have the RREF, [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1521354/265466) describes a purely mechanical way to extract a kernel basis from it. For large systems of equations, other methods (such as computing the SVD) that are more efficient and numerically stable than Gaussian elimination are used.

Comment: How can you perform Gaussian Elimination on the sample equations above to get the 3 solutions? 
In matrix form the equation would  be: [[1 1 0 -1 0], [1 0 1 0 -1] ...] * x = [0,0,0,0,0]