# Finding solution of $A\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{0}$ from rref over gf(2)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, galois-theory, gaussian-elimination, homogeneous-equation

I'm working on the Gaussian elimination being implemented on gf(2). I have successfully reduced my 286*286 matrix into rref. Now I need to find the null space of this(please tell me how to do this effectively as I'm going to hardcode this in java). It would be a great help is someone could give me the gist of finding basis and then solution of this. Also as a extra detail I'm doing all this as a part of my attempt to implement Quadratic Sieve in java.

Comment: Do you mean $A\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{0}$? And what is gf(2)?

Comment: @ThePointer Yes Ax = 0. Gf(2) is galois field of 0 and 1. The matrix will only contain 0's and 1's. It utilizes 1-bit integer arithmetic instead.  I'm stuck with solving this issue. Which in turn has been delaying the deadline for quadratic sieve implementation.

Comment: @ThePointer: I suppose it is $\mathbf F_2$ (*gf* is for Galois field).

Comment: @rajiv You need to edit your question and make it clearer.

Comment: @Bernard Ahh, ok. This is outside of my scope of knowledge.

Comment: I don't see whare the problem is. Ultimately, the RREF is in  the form  of a block-diagonal matrix, where the blocks are either the $0$-matrix or a unit matrix. Therefore the unknowns corresponding to the non-zero blocks are $0$.

Comment: @Bernard The way I'm approaching this basis of null space after rref. I'm checking the diagonal elements and if I found one that is none zero its being labeled as free variable. In this manner I'm generating an array of free variables. lets say N free variables. Out of this N variables I'm setting X free variable as 1 and rest as zero. By back substitution I'm getting a solution for this X free variable being set to one only. Is this the way to find null spaces?

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand. What is a diagonal element which is ‘none zero’?

Comment: @Bernard its a mistake from my part as i look at it now. I meant to say the one that is zero. Nevertheless is my approach correct?

Comment: You can find a purely mechanical method for extracting a kernel basis from the RREF described [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1521354/265466).

Comment: OK. If I understand well, you consider the list of variables corresponding to a diagonal $0$, which are free variables, and you consider the vectors which all coordinates $0$, but one in this list, to obtain a basis of the kernel?

Comment: @Bernard yes. Is this correct?

Comment: For me, it is perfectly correct.

Comment: @amd I went through that article. thank you!

Comment: If it answered your question, I’ll flag this one as a duplicate.