# If I have a matrix in RREF is there a quick way of pulling out vectors which are not in the span of the row vectors of A?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, matrix-equations

Say I am looking for the kernel of a linear function $\mathcal{l}_A$: $\mathbb{R}^n $->$\mathbb{R}^m$ given by the $n \times m$ matrix A. Then say A is row-equivalent to some matrix B in RREF.

Is there a quick way of pulling out the vectors which cannot be expressed as a linear combination of the row vectors in B? therefore giving me a basis for Null(A).

Comment: Firstly, $A$ should be a $m \times n$ matrix. Secondly, what do you mean by pulling out the vectors "which cannot be expressed as a linear combination of the row vectors in $B$"? Obviously you can't get them from the rows of $B$, if this is what you meant. Thirdly, just because a vector isn't expressible as a linear combination of the row vectors in $B$, doesn't mean that it is in the null space of $A$. Consider $\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\end{pmatrix}$ which has the $z$-axis as its null space; but, for example, $(0,1,1)$ is not expressible as a linear combination of the rows.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1521354/265466

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more of a long comment. Let row $1,\dots,r$ of $B$ be the non-zero rows and $j_1,\dots,j_r$ be the columns containing their leading $1$'s. Then each vector $x$ in the null space $N$ of $A$ is given by
\begin{align}
x_{j_i}=-\sum_{j\neq j_1,\dots,j_r}B_{i,j}x_j
\end{align}
for all $i=1,\dots,r$, where $x_j$ can be chosen arbitrarily for $j\neq j_1,\dots,j_r$. So one choice of a basis for $N$ consists of vectors given by setting $x_j=0$ for all but one such $j$. For example: Suppose that
\begin{align}
B=\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&-1&0&-3&-6\\
0&1&-2&0&-4&-7\\
0&0&0&1&-5&-8\\
0&0&0&0&0&0
\end{bmatrix}\,.
\end{align}
Then columns $3$, $5$ and $6$ correspond to the arbitrarily chosen $x_j$, and $N$ is spanned by
\begin{align}
{u_1}^T&=\begin{bmatrix}1&2&1&0&0&0\end{bmatrix}\,, \\
{u_2}^T&=\begin{bmatrix}3&4&0&5&1&0\end{bmatrix}\,, \\
{u_1}^T&=\begin{bmatrix}6&7&0&8&0&1\end{bmatrix}\,.
\end{align}
The point is that these vectors are determined by reading off entries of $B$. That should be quick enough.